# Visual studio 2013 connect to database using active directory

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, active-directory

I am having a ruff time connecting my MS VS2013 to a MSSQL database. Previously i had no problem when it used simple SQL server authentication but now it uses ActiveDirectory. The way i should connect is using `domain\username` and `password` but i dont know how.

[image]

This is where i am trying to create a connection to the database but I do not exactly know and cant find on the net how to configure the next window to connect to the database using active directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just specify server name, Windows authentication and then select the database from drop down. You don't need to configure anything else.

Comment: i am logged into my machine using a microsoft account  and need to use a different username and passord to connect to the server. Should i specify something in windows credentials?

Comment: No. Windows authentication means that, you need to be logged in with the account. Also, the user name and password fields remains disabled when you select Windows authentication.

Comment: So i can not log in with windows authentification and can not specify a username and password for the remote server, only if i create a account on my pc that represents that user?

Comment: Windows authentication means authenticating against an Active Directory, so, to logon to SQL Server using Windows Authentication you need to be logged on with that account in your computer. So, even if you create a local account in your pc, it won't be the same as another account with the same name in a different pc, they will have different SID's.